# Spark: display log messages

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

i am using scala application with spark dependencies . 
Here what i have

log4j.properties

```
# Here we have defined root logger
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,ERROR,R

#Direct log messages to file
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=./logging.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p  %c{1}:%L- %m%n

# Change this to set Spark log level
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR

# Silence akka remoting
#log4j.logger.Remoting=WARN

# Ignore messages below warning level from Jetty, because it's a bit verbose
#log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
```

main class

```
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure("./log4j.properties")

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("spark session example").getOrCreate
val spark = sparkSession.sqlContext

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

val log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)
log.error("This is error");
log.warn("This is warn");
println("log ok")
```

pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>com.ayd</groupId>
      <artifactId>data2</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>data2</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
       <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>

            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <version>42.1.3</version>
            </dependency>





            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

I would just to get the message i displayed me , not the spark log .
When i did this , i found this in the log file still this extra log message of spark

```
 2017-10-18 11:58:38 WARN   NativeCodeLoader:62- Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

        2017-10-18 11:58:41 ERROR  Run$:23- This is error
        2017-10-18 11:58:41 WARN   Run$:24- This is warn
```

How can i get rid of the two first line in the log file .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the level of logging for spark classes to `WARN`, so you're seeing this warning.

If you want to filter out all Spark warnings (not really recommended), you can set the level to `ERROR` in your log4j properties file:

```
# Change this to set Spark log level
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR
```

The other warning comes from Hadoop code (package `org.apache.hadoop`) - so to disable that one (along with all other Hadoop warnings) you can specify the level for that package too to be `ERROR`:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=ERROR
```

Comment: i still got this   2017-10-18 14:16:35 WARN   NativeCodeLoader:62- Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable